# Spring MVC: I want my controller to process/serve an image - it works fine in an <image> tag, but can't display when referenced directly...

Tags: html, spring, image, spring-mvc

I've got a simple controller which processes and serves an image.

## The controller:

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public byte[] GetProcessedImageResource(@RequestParam Long imageID) {

    Image image = someDAO.getImageById(imageID)
    someBusinessObject.processImage(image);

    return image == null ? null : image.getData();
}

@ModelAttribute
public void setSomeHeaders(HttpServletResponse response) {
    response.setHeader("Content-Type", "image/png");
    response.setHeader("isThisHowIAddHeaders", "yup");
}
```

## How it's invoked:

This controller is used in two contexts:

- **Context one** (which currently works perfectly - and which there is dozens of instances of all over the site): When I want to use a particular image on another page like:

  ```
  <img id="imageHolder" src="getProcessedImageResource.ctl?imageID=12345"></img>
  ```
- **context two**(which I'm having issues with): The user just goes directly to a URL by visiting, say:

  ```
  www.foo.bar.com/blah/getProcessedImageResource.ctl?imageID=12345
  ```

  in their browser(which naturally anyone can do once they've been shown the image)

## What I'm seeing:

When I intercept the response on the client side, I see "isThisHowIAddHeaders", "yup".... but I also see "Content-Type", "text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1"

In context one this works fine - the image is displayed without issue

In context two, spring-magic seems to try to marshall this bytestream into a full web page - it throws in the default header and footer and displays the image as text.

this causes two problems:

- The image is displayed as gibberish encoding instead of an image:

  .....QhÓÇÆ@BüN+?G*?3gÐèºÁ³?¯¨pTXX*ýAçýëßÒ8"¸òÿWÏ®M¦ K©æìÉ 8*oÍÚþýÀTPõæAj?.?äq*¢ê@ ?©¦Í¦÷'?¹7ì?ÞêNGçÓ~²? òò?^1?¥}Dê:Y\¨¸?e¸úÛ?ûðaZã??W1¢?¡?`Aóë??ÓefSô ??[ÜbX1×Ýµç ùõ¦*B?c]Güþ?p1¡{·Ò@?Áµ¡ãý·½?`*+N?ø[´Ñ©ëÖÇÂÿ_~=yåü(À|¿ÔzÂê@ ¾?tÙ?ÉýpIÒÿãîêGcª?Dz?Á#?òÇ]þ.8æíÍÆ¢ºqkX}?¯¿yÐÿ«íé?á?Eÿ?® §õ_?'?ºqcÎ¯õCý?»8z~}_J.....
- This text is displayed - unescaped- directly to users - and some of these images are user-submitted. I'll be honest XSS problems are my biggest concern here...

## Other things I've tried:

- Returning a ResponseEntity instead of using @ResponseBody

  ```
  HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
  headers.add("Content-Type", "image/png");
  return new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(image.getData(), headers, HttpStatus.FOUND);
  ```

  (and removing @ModelAttribute setSomeHeaders() )
- Using 'setContentType' instead

  ```
  headers.setContentType(MediaType.IMAGE_PNG);
  ```
- forcing spring to serve only the image data, with no header/footer/decoration of any kind - still get text/html content type, still get encoded image
- Intercepting the response and manually changing the content-type back to 'image/[everything I can think of]' - just to see if that's the only problem - I get an actual image this time - but completely garbled(It's supposed to be a flower by the by...) : [image]

## Questions

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here? The image seems to display fine when it's shown as part of an  tag...but when the user references it directly, and the image is served in isolation, the browser seems to refuse to display it in any sensible manner.

Comment: Can you also catch request headers? Does browser send different request headers in the two contexts? Especially take note of Accept header.

Comment: Also, does adding `@RequestMapping(...., produces = MediaType.IMAGE_PNG_VALUE)` make any difference?

Comment: @KresimirNesek The requests are different in their 'accept' headers - you're right. 

When referenced in an <image> tag, the 'accept' header is 'image/png,image/*;' but when the URL is referenced directly, the 'accept' tag is: 'ext/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;'

Comment: I'm using spring 3.0.5 unfortunately - 'produces' isn't available

Comment: Does appending &format=png to the URL help? Does changing the URL to getProcessedImageResource.png (instead of ctl) work? The issue seems to be spring's content negotiation which is somewhat inflexible in 3.0.x

Comment: @KresimirNesek if I change it to PNG the request/response mapping fails and I get a 404 :(  ... Adding &format=png seems to have no effect... Where does this content negotiation happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be Spring's content negotiation mechanism. When you return byte[] from controller method annotated with @ResponseBody, Spring will go through it's registered MessageConverters and find one that can convert byte[] to a content type requested by the browser in the Accept header (which, in your second case will not be an image, because of .ctl extension, but in first case, since URL is inside the image tag, browser will ask for an image).

Later Spring versions offer a method to specify what content type controller method produces via produces parameter in the annotation.

You may try to intercept Accept header and change it via filter in order to "fool" Spring's content negotiation (I do not recommend this, it's a hack), you may create a custom class that that represents an image (e.g. ImageBytes class that wraps byte[]) and a register a custom message converter for that class and then return the class from the controller. You may create a message converter for the Image class you use too that would behave similarly. Modifying the url with a proper extension might also work.

My recommendation is to upgrade Spring version or skip the Spring's content negotiation and message converters altogether and output the response directly:

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
public void GetProcessedImageResource(@RequestParam Long imageID, HttpServletResponse response) {

    Image image = someDAO.getImageById(imageID)
    someBusinessObject.processImage(image);

    response.setContentType(MediaType.IMAGE_PNG_VALUE);
    FileCopyUtils.copy(image.getData(), response.outputStream)

}
```

**EDIT**

After a bit more research, Spring seems to have a BufferedImageMessageConverter too: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/BufferedImageHttpMessageConverter.html

It seems that this message converter is not registered by default. Another approach to the solution which may work would be to register this converter and return BufferedImage directly from the controller.

Comment: Thanks for all the pointers! Have I been looking at this too long without coffee - or should that method have a return type? is it just void? also should it be getOutputStream()?

Comment: You're right :) It should be void and it shouldn't have @ResponseBody

Comment: I can't upgrade spring and I'd already spent too long wrestling with the spring content negotiation. I just gave up and wrote directly to the response in the controller as you advised, and it worked perfectly.

Comment: yep - fully tested and this is definitely a valid solution to my problem - Thanks again for all the help buddy!